# bin_at in dlmalloc

Tags: c, malloc

In glibc malloc.c or dlmalloc It said "**repositioning tricks**"As in blew, and use this trick in bin_at.

bins is a array,the space is allocated when av(struct malloc_state) is allocated.doesn't it? the sizeof(bin[i]) is less then sizeof(struct malloc_chunk*)?

When bin_at(M,1)(which is used as unsorted_chunks) is called,the result is: bin[0] - offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd) bin[0] - 8 is right?

Who can describe this trick for me? I can't understand the bin_at macro.why they get the bins address use this method?how it works?

Very thanks,and sorry for my poor English.

```
/*
     To simplify use in double-linked lists, each bin header acts
    as a malloc_chunk. This avoids special-casing for headers.
    But to conserve space and improve locality, we allocate
    only the fd/bk pointers of bins, and then use repositioning tricks
    to treat these as the fields of a malloc_chunk*.
*/

typedef struct malloc_chunk* mbinptr;

/* addressing -- note that bin_at(0) does not exist */
#define bin_at(m, i) \
  (mbinptr) (((char *) &((m)->bins[((i) - 1) * 2]))               \
         - offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd))
```

The malloc_chunk struct like this:

```
struct malloc_chunk {

  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      prev_size;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T      size;       /* Size in bytes, including overhead. */

  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

  /* Only used for large blocks: pointer to next larger size.  */
  struct malloc_chunk* fd_nextsize; /* double links -- used only if free. */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk_nextsize;
};
```

And the bin type like this:

```
typedef struct malloc_chunk* mbinptr;

struct malloc_state {
  /* Serialize access.  */
  mutex_t mutex;

  /* Flags (formerly in max_fast).  */
  int flags;

#if THREAD_STATS
  /* Statistics for locking.  Only used if THREAD_STATS is defined.  */
  long stat_lock_direct, stat_lock_loop, stat_lock_wait;
#endif

  /* Fastbins */
  mfastbinptr      fastbinsY[NFASTBINS];

  /* Base of the topmost chunk -- not otherwise kept in a bin */
  mchunkptr        top;

  /* The remainder from the most recent split of a small request */
  mchunkptr        last_remainder;

  /* Normal bins packed as described above */
  mchunkptr        bins[NBINS * 2 - 2];

  /* Bitmap of bins */
  unsigned int     binmap[BINMAPSIZE];

  /* Linked list */
  struct malloc_state *next;

#ifdef PER_THREAD
  /* Linked list for free arenas.  */
  struct malloc_state *next_free;
#endif

  /* Memory allocated from the system in this arena.  */
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T system_mem;
  INTERNAL_SIZE_T max_system_mem;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably `struct malloc_chunk` looks something like:

```
struct malloc_chunk {
    /* ... fields here ... */
    struct malloc_chunk *fd;
    struct malloc_chunk *bk;
    /* ... more fields here ... */
};
```

...and the `->bins` type looks like:

```
struct {
    struct malloc_chunk *fd;
    struct malloc_chunk *bk;
};
```

The `bin_at` macro makes a pointer to the latter structure into a fake pointer to the former structure, for the purpose of accessing the `fd` and `bk` members only (since they're the only ones that exist in the smaller one).  ie `bin_at(m, i)->fd` and `bin_at(m, i)->bk` are the same as `m->bins[(i - 1) * 2].fd` and `m->bins[(i - 1) * 2].bk`, but `bin_at` can be used in places that expect a `struct malloc_chunk *` (as long as they only use the `fd` and `bk` members).

It's a bit of a hack.  I wouldn't do this in your own code - remember Kernighan's advice about writing code as cleverly as possible:

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing
>   the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as
>   cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug
>   it." – Brian W. Kernighan

---

OK, so `->bins` isn't an array of structs at all - it's an array of `struct malloc_chunk *`.

Notice that `->bins[(i - 1) * 2]` refers to the i-th *pair* of `struct malloc_chunk *` pointers in the `->bins` array.  This pair is equivalent to the `fd` and `bk` pair of pointers in a `struct malloc_chunk`, with the first (`->bins[(i - 1) * 2]`) being equivalent to `fd` (they could have instead made `->bins` an array of the smaller struct I suggested above; it would be functionally equivalent and probably clearer).

The `bin_at` macro lets the code insert one of those pairs of pointers that are in the `->bins` array into a linked list of `struct malloc_chunk` structs - without allocating an entire `struct malloc_chunk`.  This is the space saving they are talking about.

The `bin_at` macro takes a index into the `bins` array, then does "if this pointer was actually the `fd` value in a `struct malloc_chunk`, then calculate a pointer to where that `struct malloc_chunk` would be".  It does this by subtracting the offset of the `fd` member within a `struct malloc_chunk` from the address of the item in the `bins` array.

It doesn't really "locate the `bins[i]`" - that's straightforward (`&bins[i]`).  It actually locates the *imaginary* `struct malloc_chunk` that `bins[i]` is the `fd` member of.

Sorry, it's complicated to explain because it's a complicated concept.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.
 But I still don't know how it can conserve space,and how it locate the bin[i].
 I edited the question and pasted some more code.would you please describe it in detail?